# React Hooks: Why is .current null for useRef Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple example of a component:

```
function App() {
  const observed = useRef(null);
  console.log(observed.current);

  return (
    <div ref={observed} className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I would expect that `observed.current` would be of type element and current would not be empty but the div element with all its properties. My understanding would be:

1. The ref is initialised with a value of null
2. Null is overwritten by the ref

But as it turns out, `.current` remains empty. This is bad since I want to pass observed to a function that expects an argument of type Element.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/purple-forest-0460k

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`Ref.current` is null because the ref is not set till after the function returns and the content is rendered. The [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook fires every time the value of contents of the array passed to it changes. By passing `observed` in the array and by passing a callback that logs `observed` to the console, the useEffect hook can be leveraged to accomplish your task.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(observed.current);
  }, [observed]);
```

Edit: This only works on the first render as changes to a ref do not trigger re-renders. But the general statement about useEffect still holds. If you want to observe changes to a ref of a dom element, you can use a [callback as ref.](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

```js
  <div 
    ref={el => { console.log(el); observed.current = el; }} // or setState(el)
    className="App"
  >
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-payne-eyk5f)

Comment: Great thanks! I am quite know to Hooks but for a functional component I would assume that the whole function is the "render function". Do you may have a reference of things I can and can't do in a render function?

Comment: Great thanks! I am quite know to Hooks but for a functional component I would assume that the whole function is the "render function". Do you may have a reference of things I can and can't do in a render function?

Comment: _"You have to check for the value inside a `useEffect` hook"_ - this statement is not _strictly_ true, I could have a memoised callback function that that can access a ref. The main point is the ref is null because the UI hasn't actually rendered yet, `useEffect` works here because `useEffect` it's the equivalent to `componentDidMount` and a few other hooks that run _after_ the component has rendered.

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply that useEffect was the only hook. But for OP's use case there is no point in using a memoized callback. Because his task is to console.log. Yes I have mentioned that point in my text. yes, useEffect fires every time the contents of the array in the 2nd parameter changes.

Comment: Can you guys specify what a memorised callback is? Is it a useMemo hook? Its not a term with lots of google results.

Comment: @Jame Changed text, should be clearer for future readers. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: @AvinKavish edit looks much better IMO :) Xen_mar check out [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: I think useEffect will run only once because observed will never change even if observed.current changes. That is the point of useRef. "The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component." https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-tharp-dsnpx

Comment: In my case it has been set before, but a little bit later it becomes null again.

Comment: Using refs as useEffect() dependencies is, imo, an antipattern.  Any future changes to ref.current will not trigger the useEffect().

Comment: @WestonWedding this is not a pattern at all, It's a simple and quick way to get the ref printed to the console because the useEffect hook runs after the first render. Yes, since refs exist outside react state, changes to the value will not trigger re-renders. Updated answer.

Answer (score 24):

This is what I ended up doing since calling `useEffect` on `rlvRef` did not capture all events.

```
const rlvRef = useRef()
const [refVisible, setRefVisible] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if (!refVisible) { 
    return
  }
  // detected rendering
}, refVisible)

return (
  <RecyclerListView
    ref={el => { rlvRef.current = el; setRefVisible(!!el); }}
    ... 
  />
)
```

Comment: Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property

Comment: No, `rlvRef.current` is not a read only value. The reference is a `const` but `.current` is mutable.

Comment: Anybody stumbling over this: In Typescript, try: `useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)` (if the element is a `<div>`). Weirdly, adding `| null` to the type fixes the error.

Comment: Good answer @manmal Seems it was a simple typing issue for me.

Answer (score 18):

At the time the `console.log` happens, the `ref` isn't yet set. Try putting your `console.log` into a `useEffect` hook and it works as you want it to.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const observed = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(observed.current);
  }, [observed]);

  return (
    <div ref={observed} className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Why would this work? `observed` is a Ref and will therefore not trigger any reruns. So if no other part of the code will trigger a rerender the Ref will always stay null until something does rerender.

Comment: @mleister as the observed reference is provided its current value at the point of being given to the div, thus App renders once with a current value of null, then is passed to the div, is given the value and App re-renders as observed has changed - thus the log.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set a value into the useRef()-variable which was retrieved by an async http-request and was saved in a useState()-variable. So i needed to provide it as an dependency as well in the useEffect()-function:

```
    const [object, setObject] = useState('');

    const fetchObject = useCallback(async () => {
        const res = await fetch(apiUrl + "/object/", {});
        setObject({ ...await res.json() });
    }, [apiUrl]);

    const jsonEditor = React.createRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchObject();
        if (jsonEditor.current && object.json) {
            jsonEditor.current.jsonEditor.set(JSON.parse(object.json));
        }
    }, [fetchObject, object.json]);

return (
    <div>
        <JsonEditor
            ref={jsonEditor}
            onChangeText={onChangeTextHandler}
        />
    </div>);
```