# How to pass a reference created by react hook of parent component to child components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref, react-forwardref, use-ref

**My Code:**

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {

const ParentReference = useRef(null);

return(
<Parent className="d-flex flex-row" ref={ParentReference}>
          <ChildComponent
            className="mr-3"
            target={ParentReference.current}
          />
          <AnotherChild className="mr-3" />
        </Nav>
)};
```

As seen in the code above, I have created a reference using useRef hook and attached it to my ParentComponent.
Now am passing to ChildComponent by means of target prop and using it to do some dom manipulation inside the child.

**Issue :** 
I am getting *ParentReference* as **null** for the first render of the component. (If I force re-render on change of the ParentReference it will update and re-render whole component then it will have value.)

How to get the ParentReference inside my child Component for initial render itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: Why is .current null for useRef Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541342/react-hooks-why-is-current-null-for-useref-hook)

Comment: No it doesn't. the question they mentioned is quite different as in My ref is attached and initialised to parent component before it is passed to child component, so i expect it to have value.
I can use useEffect hook and trigger re-render on change of ref value which will  re-render the component again. But i want to have in first render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

segFault's reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541342/react-hooks-why-is-current-null-for-useref-hook) is correct.  Your ref it not initialized until *after* your component's first render.  So when you render your `<ChildComponent target={ParentReference.current} />`, the ref is not yet defined.

In this scenario you might consider using a `useEffect` to set a state variable on first render, and conditionally rendering the `<ChildComponent />` once that state variable is set.

```
const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {

const ParentReference = useRef(null);

// define state variable defining the ref as not yet ready
const [refReady, setRefReady] = useState(false)
// On first mount, set the variable to true, as the ref is now available
useEffect( () => {
  setRefReady(true)
}, [])

return(
<Parent className="d-flex flex-row" ref={ParentReference}>
          {refReady && <ChildComponent
            className="mr-3"
            target={ParentReference.current}
          />}
          <AnotherChild className="mr-3" />
        </Nav>
)};
```

Comment: yes, you are correct \n
```
  const [, reRender] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    reRender({});
  }, [ParentReference]);
```
I was doing this but i am expecting if we can do something in first render??

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  Refs are something of an anti-pattern when working with React, so you should try to be sure you really need to use a ref, as opposed to passing a prop, or managing state from the Grandparent.  What are you trying to accomplish by passing the ref here?  Also if this answer helped you it is customary to mark it as the answer and / or upvote it.  Everyone loves meaningless internet points.

Comment: I have an overlay inside my child component which i want to position it with reference to my parent's component.

Comment: this sounds like something that could be done with css.  if you post more code and/or create a working example (codesandbox or something similar), and give a bit more detail on what exactly you want to accomplish in terms of positioning, perhaps we could help you figure it out a bit better.