# useRef.current always returns undefined when useRef is used in react-router <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a ref by using **useRef** hook and add this ref to a react-router ***Link***. Then inside **useEffect** hook I am trying to access my ref's **current** attribute but it is always **undefined**. I have used **useRef** the same way in multiple occasions with custom components or common html elements and it always work. Any ideas on why it doesn't work with ***Link***?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MyComponent = ({ code, getCode }) => {
  const linkRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = linkRef || {};
    if (linkRef !== undefined && current) {
      console.log(current); // current is always undefined and it shouldn't
      console.log(code);
    }
  }, [code, linkRef]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link
        ref={linkRef}
        to={{
          pathname: '/enter-code',
          query: { code },
        }}
      >
        {'Link'}
      </Link>
      <button onClick={() => getCode()} type="button">
        {'Get Code'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  code: PropTypes.string,
  getCode: PropTypes.func,
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I am using:

```
"react": "^16.12.0"
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
```

Comment: what version of `react` and `react-router` do you use?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I just edited the question, adding the versions.

Comment: It may be related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56541342/806975

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez I have also tried pass the ref as a dependency to the useEffect and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use click on Link.

As the typescript error says, Link component cannot be clicked as simply an anchor tag. There are two proposed solutions to this.

1. Change Link to  and use HTMLAnchorElement type in the useRef.
2. Or if you want to stay using Link component from react-router-dom, you can access the props of the link component. You can access the "to" of the link but make sure to just have direct URL specified in "to" props.

   `if (linkRef !== undefined && current) {`                        `window.location.assign(linkRef.current.props.to.toString()); // redirect to the to prop on Link component }`

Comment: That answers probably a next problem I was going to face and thanks in advance but the actual question here is why 'current' is always undefined. I am facing this problem before I even reach to the point I am trying to click the button.
linkRef.current is always undefined

Comment: You can consider replacing it with anchor tag if it suits you

Comment: <Link to="/" innerRef={linkRef } />   // Try using innerRef instaed of ref

Comment: I want to open a new tab at '/enter-code' and also pass the code as property to use in the new page. This is why I am using react-router and not just an anchor tag.

Comment: I have tried innerRef also. Same behaviour and after some research after React 16 there is no need for innerRef, ref is handled as well.