# DOM Element Returning Null on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

### [EDIT] HAS BEEN FIXED (scroll to bottom)

Hi I am trying to select a react element for a functional component, current code:

```
const Emoji = (props) => {

  const copyButton = useRef(null);

  function handleHover(e) {
    console.log(this.copyButton); //want to select this element
  }

  function handleMouseOut(e) {

  }

  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div id={"emoji-"+props.id} className="emoji" onMouseOver={handleHover} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}>
        <Button ref={copyButton} className="copyButton" buttonText="Copy" buttonColour="primary" />
        <Button className="button" buttonText="Information" buttonColour=" " />
        <h1>{props.emojiCharacter}</h1>
        <p>{props.emojiName}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Emoji;
```

I am trying to build an app where when the user hovers over this component the buttons will appear, but when I try to select them I keep getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'copyButton' of undefined`

It also returns null when I try to `document.getElementById` as well.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

### FIXED

The problem was due to the element being a custom component and not a default component, otherwise I could've simply just used `copyButton.current`

I fixed it by going into the component's jsx and changing the `const Button = (props) => { etc }` declaration to a

```
const Button = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} 
    </div>
));
```

This article did it https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: This looks like a function component and not a class component, so you wouldn't use the `this` keyword. have you tried just `console.log(copyButton);`?

Comment: This looks like a `functional component`, so you shouldn't be doing `this.copyButton`, just `copyButton`

Comment: Please check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541342/react-hooks-why-is-current-null-for-useref-hook/56541442

Answer (score 1):

`copyButton` will not be ready on the first cycle of render you need to  test before invoking it, and you will need to use `copyButton.current`

```
const handleMousehover =() =>{
  if(copyButton && copyButton.current){
   // add your code here
  }
}
```

You will not need to test if the hover is comming from where you used `ref={copyButton}`, but if it is comming from somewhere else, there is no garenty that it will not be null (or it became null for some reason), so it is a good practice to test it always.

Comment: Why do you think the button will not be ready on initial render ?

Comment: it is a functional component,and the "function" will run the first time to calculate what it should display, the code will run before "return" which will return the dom, this means you can't use `copyButton` in the first cycle, because it will be null

Comment: No my friend. It's not correct in case of Functional components. I use useRef everyday :) Try to do one small test create a functional component and use console.log() at the top just before you declare useState() and see if it gets rendered... One more thing Questioner says they want this effect on However :) Hope that clears the doubt :) Best wishes

Comment: It's still returning null, I think the problem is it due to it being a custom component and not a default HTML element, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `copyButton.current` to select your `ref={copyButton}` Button.

> The useRef Hook is a function that returns a mutable ref object whose
> .current property is initialized with the passed argument
> (initialValue.)The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

```
const Emoji = (props) => {

  const copyButton = useRef(null);

  function handleHover(e) {
    console.log(copyButton.current); //want to select this element
  }

  function handleMouseOut(e) {

  }

  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div id={"emoji-"+props.id} className="emoji" onMouseOver={handleHover} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}>
        <Button ref={copyButton} className="copyButton" buttonText="Copy" buttonColour="primary" />
        <Button className="button" buttonText="Information" buttonColour=" " />
        <h1>{props.emojiCharacter}</h1>
        <p>{props.emojiName}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Emoji;
```

**NOTE:**  Coming to the second part of the question. You will ned to set styles within your `handleHover()` function for show and hide logic.

Something like this :) Just a demo. Implement it as per your requirement

```
  function handleHover(e) {
    console.log(copyButton.current); 
    copyButton.current.style.display="block";
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, it stills appears to be returning null :/, any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is due to it not being a default HTML element and a custom element because when I add it to the div above it the console.log seems to work.