# Object is possibly null in TypeScript, but object cannot be null given the context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why does TypeScript complain of an object being possibly null when it clearly cannot be?

[image]

Full code as per request:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const inputRef = useRef(null)

  const checkValidity = () => {
    
    // This checks if the variables are null
    if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {

      const valid = inputRef.current.checkValidity()

      console.log(valid)

    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={checkValidity}>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef}/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: My _assumption_ is that when you do `useRef(null)` you are essentially assigning `inputRef.current` to be `null`

Comment: The problem is here `const inputRef = useRef(null)`

Comment: not within the code block as a check is performed: `if (inputRef && inputRef.current)`. In this scenario, `inputRef` and `inputRef.current` cannot be `null`.

Comment: It's not reproducible, I'm not getting that error,.. I get this error -> `Property 'checkValidity' does not exist on type 'never'.`,   As a quick hack for that you could do -> `React.useRef(null as any)` for now.

Comment: Could you remove the `null` inside the `useRef` parameter and will see about the behavior?

Comment: @VagnerWentz  The null should be fine, as he's using a type guard anyway..  The only real issue with using null,  null certainly doesn't have a property called checkValidity..

Comment: @Keith I know, I would like to see about the behavior.

Comment: @VagnerWentz removing `null` makes no difference.

Comment: It seems that `useRef<HTMLInputElement>()` works. Can someone explain why a check for `null` does not get rid of initial error? Error gone when specifying `HTMLInputElement`. Will happily give answer to a good explanation.

Comment: Scrap that, this now breaks my passing of ref to input with `Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<null>'`

Comment: @shennan Yes, the correct way is use `useRef<HTMLInputElement>()` because if you think about, we want to make a reference about a some input text, maybe the problem about the `null` even you verifying it is about some problem in React

Comment: @shennan Maybe this post could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541342/react-hooks-why-is-current-null-for-useref-hook

Comment: `React.useRef(null as HTMLInputElement | null)`   You will notice if you hover over `inputRef.current` the type guard will also work now.

Comment: Also  `if (inputRef.current)` should be enough,  `inputRef` can't be null after all.

Comment: Please vote to re-open question; moderator was far too quick to close.

Comment: Actually doing -> `const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);`  eg, doing what you said but also setting null seems to work for me.

Comment: try this one `const valid = inputRef?.current.checkValidity()`