# Cannot useRef() in functional component. null is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a functional component which causes the following error:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'textInput.current.blur'

I wonder why

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native";

const UselessTextInput = ({ hide }) => {
    const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("Useless Text");
    const textInput = useRef(null);

    const _renderInput = () => {
        if (hide) textInput.current.blur();
        <TextInput
            ref={textInput}
            onFocus={() => ...}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            value={text} />

    ...

    return __renderInput();
}
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: Why is .current null for useRef Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541342/react-hooks-why-is-current-null-for-useref-hook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to your `textInput` value

like this : `textInput?.current?.blur();`

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Well yeah, I know what optional chaining is. But why is it needed here?

Comment: @Stophface for the first run, your textInput current  value is null, you can't access to blur from a null value, so you just need to add a check for your current value

Answer (score 1):

If you set a ref to a DOM node using the `ref` attribute, the ref's `current` property will have that node only after it's set i.e. in `useEffect` callbacks or from next renders.

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const divRef = React.useRef("initval");

  console.log("During Render", divRef.current);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Inside useEffect CB", divRef.current); 
  }, []);

  return <button ref={divRef} onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Understanding the flow:**

- When `useRef` is called React returns an object whose `current` property is set to the initial value provided (`"initval"` in our case).
- So, the console log during first render prints the initial value.
- Then the JSX is returned from the component, which updates the ref and sets it's `current` property to the DOM node.
- Then the callback passed `useEffect` runs and since the ref has already been updated it prints the DOM node.
- Then in next render (which can be triggered by clicking on the button), again we call `useRef` and React returns the same object and therefore this time the log during the render prints the DOM node.