# can not access or manipulate the dom using references in react

Tags: reactjs, dom, height

I tried to access the dom to get the height of a specific element in react using useRef() hook, and assign the height of another element to it, so its height would change dynamically based on the height change of the reference element and I used the height.current.clientHeight property but I encountered an error message saying:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'clientHeight')

and here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import MenuIcon from "./MenuIcon";
import { useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import bg from "../public/bg.jpg";
import { useRef } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const height = useRef(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(!open);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <MenuIcon bgC="bg-white" handle={handleClick} open={open} />
      <div className="w-full relative h-[40%]" ref={height}>
        <nav className="xs:max-md:hidden flex z-20 justify-between md:max-lg:justify-end md:max-lg:gap-24 text-white bg-transparent backdrop-blur-lg  py-3 px-6 ">
          <div className="hover:text-gray-300 hover:text-[20px] ease-in duration-100">
            <Link href="/">About me</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="hover:text-gray-300 hover:text-[20px] ease-in duration-100">
            <Link href="/">My skills</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="hover:text-gray-300 hover:text-[20px] ease-in duration-100">
            <Link href="/">Portfolio</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="hover:text-gray-300 hover:text-[20px] ease-in duration-100">
            <Link href="/">Contacts</Link>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <Image
          src={bg}
          layout="responsive"
          objectFit="contain"
          width={400}
          height={400}
          alt="/"
        />

        <div className="w-full h-full bg-black/40 absolute top-0 lef-0 right-0">
          <h1 className="text-white w-[75%] font-Neo font-[12px] box-border text-2xl mx-auto text-center translate-y-[140px]">
            Hi there! My name is Alharith and I am a front-end developer.
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={
          open
            ? `w-auto h-${height.current.clientHeight} box-border px-12 bg-blue-400 backdrop-blur-sm fixed top-0 right-0 translate-x-0 duration-300 ease-in flex flex-col items-center justify-around text-2xl`
            : `w-auto h-${height.current.clientHeight} px-12 py-[30px] bg-transparent backdrop-blur-sm fixed top-0 right-0 translate-x-[100%] duration-300 ease-in flex flex-col items-center justify-around text-2xl`
        }
      >
        <div className="w-full flex flex-col justify-around items-center h-[50%] gap-8 text-2xl font-Neo">
          <div className="font-Neo text-2xl hover:text-[20px] hover:text-gray-100 duration-100 ease-in">
            <Link href="/">About me</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="font-Neo text-2xl hover:text-[20px] hover:text-gray-100 duration-100 ease-in">
            <Link href="/">My Skills</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="font-Neo text-2xl hover:text-[20px] hover:text-gray-100 duration-100 ease-in">
            <Link href="/">Portfolio</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="font-Neo text-2xl hover:text-[20px] hover:text-gray-100 duration-100 ease-in">
            <Link href="/">Contacts</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I tried checking if the "height.current !== null" and if true would assign the value of the clientHeight to another variable, if not would assign "auto" as so:

const hi = height.current ? `${height.current.clientHeight}` : "auto"

still getting the same error

I expected it to work fine but it really didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useRef` hook variable doesn't get the `current` property immediately. This gets populated after the initial DOM render.

To get this working, add a `useEffect` hook with `height.current` in dependency array.

And use a flag with `useState` hook and inside `useEffect` hook, update the flag.

```
 const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
    if(height.current) setFlag(true);
 }, [height.current]);

 // and use the flag in div class
 <div 
    className={ open && flag ? `w-auto h-${height.current.clientHeight}...` }
 >
 //
 </div>
```

For more info, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541342/react-hooks-why-is-current-null-for-useref-hook)

Comment: You mean the useRef hook does not get the properties of the DOM Node from the first render? Like It has to be re-rendered and that’s why to use a useEffect? To skip the initial value to the current property?

Comment: No, it populates `current` after first render of the component only. But in your code, you are trying to access it even before the first render by using it in same component. Thats why you should use `useEffect` to ensure that current is accessed once the component is rendered.

Comment: It worked now and now I understand thank you so much Ravi! here's the test code I made that worked:

Comment: great! glad it helped, please accept the this answer to help other finding the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the value of the **useRef** hook when the component is rendering. You should use the **useRef** hook after the component is rendered.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const height = useRef(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(!open);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("heightRef.current.clientHeight", height.current.clientHeight);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={handleClick} open={open}>
        button
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: open ? 100 : 300 }}
        ref={height}
      >
        useref
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Maybe it can work for you.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const height = useRef(null);

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(!open);
  }
    
  // prepare value after re-rendering componenet
  const preparedHeight = height.current ? height.current.clientHeight : 0;

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={handleClick} open={open}>
        button
      </div>
      <div
        className="height-ref-class"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: open ? 100 : 300 }}
        ref={height}
      >
        useref {preparedHeight}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```